# zookeeper launch error when in single node mode

Tags: launch, apache-zookeeper

Here is the command line:
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties

Here is the output:
[2013-04-15 18:18:05,570] INFO tickTime set to 3000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2013-04-15 18:18:05,570] INFO minSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2013-04-15 18:18:05,570] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2013-04-15 18:18:05,590] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2013-04-15 18:18:05,601] INFO Reading snapshot /tmp/zookeeper/version-2/snapshot.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileSnap)
[2013-04-15 18:18:05,607] INFO Snapshotting: 0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog)

It gets stuck here and never moves forward

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i tried it out it does stop there but the server is running so this seems to be default behavior. try connecting to the ZooKeeper instance through zkClient it is working properly :).

Answer (score 0):

It means your service is working fine. 
Use [nohup](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/). It runs your command in the background and you don't have to wait for it.